# Does a Laplacian matrix characterize a Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Given a Laplacian matrix can we have more than one graphs that has the given Laplacian?

Also is there any work on how to construct a graph, given its corresponding Laplacian matrix?

Comment: Wouldn't putting an edge between $i$ and $j$ iff $a_{ij}$ is -1 consist of an explicit construction of a graph given a Laplacian?

Comment: Oh yea you are right. So then that would also answer the first question then, there is a one to one correspondence between laplacian and the graph?

Comment: @Mike Though the weights can be an issue in this case no? We know the sum of the degrees of all edges incident on a vertex and we need to figure out which edge has how much weight.

Comment: Given a (labelled) graph $G$ set $a_{ij} = -1$ iff there is an edge in $G$ between $i$ and $j$. If $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic then the Laplacian of $G$ can be obtained from the Laplacian of $G'$ by applying the same permutation to the rows and columns of the Laplacian of $G$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the Laplacian captures the weight: If there is an edge between $i$ and $j$ with weight $w_{ij}$ then $a_{ij} = w_{ij}$. Excuse me, $-w_{ij}$

Comment: You are right. I was mixing up weighted and unweighted laplacians.